# Display the number of suppliers in each country

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is "Display the country and the number of suppliers in each country from the suppliers table. Eliminate any supplier that is from a city that starts with the letter "S". Eliminate any groups whose supplier count is greater than 3."
This is what I have so far:

```
select COUNTRY, count(SUPPLIERID)as "SUPPLIERCOUNT"
from SUPPLIERS
where CITY not like 'S%'
  and SUPPLIERID <= '3'
group by country
order by count (supplierid) asc
```

I believe I have accomplished the first part, please correct me if I'm wrong, but I am having trouble 'Eliminating any groups whose supplier count is greater than '3'.

I have tried doing `count(SUPPLIERID)` , `count (SUPPLIERID)` , `SUPPLIERCOUNT <=...` , `count(SUPPLIERCOUNT)` , and basically anything I could think of. If I simply put SUPPLIERID, it brings back results but it is wrong. I know it is the how I am writing the identifier, but I don't know what else I could put. If you could get back to me soon that would be a lot of help, thank you!

Comment: `HAVING count(SUPPLIERID) <= 3`

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware 'having' was even valid, but anyway it worked so thanks!